# Importing Excel dates into MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, date-conversion

I have been trying to solve this issue for the past few days with no luck, can someone please help?!?

I am trying to read in some financial time series, uniquely identified by date, however I can not get MAYLAB to properly import the dates. For example, here is a sample record:

```
12/31/14    114.89    ...
```

Using [`xlsread()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) it performs some date conversion that I can not figure out (mathematically), but here is what I get:

```
40542    114.89    ...
```

I am using this conversion factor, but it is not working: `datestr(dateNumToConvert+693960,'yyyymmdd');`

I cannot figure this out, can someone please point me in the right direction? This is being performed using MATLAB R2014a on OS X 10.9

Comment: thanks! without changing anything it will convert to a day ahead, but these 3 lines did the trick! x = xlsread('test.xlsx');
mx = x2mdate(x(:,1)-1,1);
datestr(mx)

Answer (score 1):

Today is 02/03/2015, that Excel store as `42065`.

```
>> datestr(42065 + 693960, 'dd/mm/yyyy')

ans =

02/03/2015
```

Your date `31/12/2014` in Excel is `42004`, so we obtain:

```
datestr(42004 + 693960, 'dd/mm/yyyy')

ans =

31/12/2014
```

Note that, in MATLAB environment:

```
>> today

ans =

      736025
```

That confirm:

```
>> 42065 + 693960

ans =

      736025
```